# Symplectic basis

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\omega$ be a holomorphic one-form on a Riemann surface $X$ of genus $g$. Can one find a symplectic basis $(a_i,b_i)$ for $H_1(X,\mathbb{R})$ such that $\int_{a_i}\omega=\delta_{i1}$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true, not even if we ignore the word "symplectic."

For example, on $\mathbb{C}$ mod the Gaussian integers, you can't make a basis of the $\mathbb{R}$-valued homology such that $\int_{e_1} dz = 0$ but $\int_{e_2} dz = 1$. Indeed the integral of $dz$ over a real-linear combination of cycles $a \gamma_1 + b \gamma_i$ (here $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_i$ denote the images of line segments from 0 to 1 or 0 to $i$ respectively) is just $a + bi$ which vanishes if and only if $a = b = 0$.

The problem is that you need complex linear combinations of cycles, not just real-linear combinations, to annihilate holomorphic forms, which isn't surprising since they live in $H^1(X, \mathbb{C})$ and not $H^1(X, \mathbb{R})$.

(If the $\mathbb{R}$ in the question was a typo for $\mathbb{C}$, the answer is yes -- you can extend $\omega$ to a symplectic basis (possibly scaling) and take the dual basis (possibly scaling again).)